# Trim quote mark in MySQL

Tags: mysql, trim

Can anyone tell me what have I got wrong here?

```
UPDATE `oc_product`
SELECT `model` = TRIM(BOTH ''' FROM '`model`')
```

The database is ocart2, the table is oc_product and the column is model.

I am trying to remove the `'` from a model number.

eg: it currently is `'123456'` I want it to be `123456`

Answer (score 2):

This is the proper syntax

```
UPDATE `oc_product` SET `model` = TRIM(BOTH '\'' FROM model);
```

Comment: Thanks that worked a treat